# chart canvas js set dynamic array

Tags: javascript, canvas, canvasjs

I receive json, and  try set dynamic array to dataPoints of chart canvasJS, maybe somebody can help please,

this the code:

```
for(var i=0;i<cars.length; i++) {
    cars[i] =100 * (cars[i]/cars.length);
}

for(var j=0;j<cars.length; j++){
    dps.push({
        y: cars[j], label: models[j]
    });
}
```

And this code how I build canvasJS chart:

```
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    animationEnabled: true,
    title: {
        text: "Sum of Cars"
    },
    data: [{
        type: "pie",
        startAngle: 240,
        yValueFormatString: "##0.00\"%\"",
        indexLabel: "{label} {y}",
        dataPoints: dps
    }]
});    

chart.render();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating `dps` won't have any effect on the CanvasJS Chart Options. You will either have to [update the chart options](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/basics-of-creating-html5-chart/updating-chart-options/) yourself and re-render the chart.

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    chart.options.data[0].dataPoints.push(data[i]);
}
```

The second approach would be updating the dataPoints using [set() method](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/methods/dataseries/set/).

```
chart.data[0].set("dataPoints", data);
```

**Note** the chart has to be rendered before you can use any set() method.

Have a look at these examples:

1. [Updating dataPoints using chart options](https://jsfiddle.net/0o1h5pgm/).
2. [Updating dataPoints using set method](https://jsfiddle.net/9r4mweha/).

Comment: I want to say BIG THANK YOU! its very help me!